# Membership.GeneratePassword

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, smtp

I need to send a temporary password via email to an user when i register a new Teacher.
i use Membership.GeneratePassword to generate random password.
here is my TeacherController

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(TeacherViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var model = new TeacherViewModel()
            {
                Courses = _context.Courses.ToList(),
                SituationActuelles = _context.SituationActuelles.ToList()
            };

            return View("Create", model);
        }

        var teacher = new Teacher
        {               
            PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber,
            Password = viewModel.Password
        };
        _context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        var body = "<p>Merci de votre interet a NewEra Tutoring Corp.</p> <br/>" +
                   "Vos credentials pour acceder a votre platform est le suivant: <br/>" +
                   "Email: Votre email<br/>" +
                   "Votre mot de passe temporaire: " + viewModel.Password;
        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(viewModel.Email));  // replace with valid value 
        message.From = new MailAddress("recrutement@newera-tutoring.com");  // replace with valid value
        message.Subject = "Your email subject";
        message.Body = string.Format(body, "NewEra Tutoring", "recrutement@newera-tutoring.com", "Votre identifiant pour NewEra Tutoring");
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credential = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = "recrutement@newera-tutoring.com",  // replace with valid value
                Password = "neweratutoring"  // replace with valid value
            };
            smtp.Credentials = credential;
            smtp.Host = "gator4123.hostgator.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

But the password i receive in the email it's different from the one that it's saved in the database.

here is my model

```
TeacherViewModel{
    public string Password => Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 1);
```

}

Where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've used an expression bodied member in the view model for the password property which essentially creates a get wrapper around the call to membership password.

Each time you access the property it generates a new password as it runs the function again.

I don't see why you'd want to have it in the view model at all unless your intention is to offer a random password that they user could replace with their own.  If that was the aim use a standard property get/set and create an initial password value in the view model constructor instead.  Otherwise, take it out o of the view model & only create the password in the post action if every thing else is valid.